# Need help solving this SQL query to understand

Tags: mysql, hive

write an sql to generate the report for employee dataset with give condition if average age >35 then states value is ok else notok dataset

```
id name age dept salary 

1 tt 51 it 4000 
2 kk 56 it 6000 
3 mm 45 sales 7000 
4 kk 25 sales 9000 
5 op 24 hr 4000 
6 op 24 hr 8000
```

output

```
dept avgage states 
it 53.5 ok 
sales 35 ok 
hr 24 notok
```

Comment: Share Code and Please explain your problem clearly...

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
SELECT a.dept,
       a.avgage,
       CASE
         WHEN a.avgage >= 35 THEN 'ok'
         ELSE 'notok'
       END states
FROM   (SELECT dept,
               Avg (age) avgage
        FROM   employee
        GROUP  BY dept) a
ORDER  BY avgage DESC;
```

**Note**: Please show some effort to understand and write a query on your own.